# Change of background color in table column based on condition in Reporting

Tags: c#, reporting-services, devexpress

i have created table, where i need to change background color of columns based on value of first row of that column.

if first row value of particular column is 0 or  hyphen(-), i need to change 
1.) background  color of that column rows to grey otherwise transparent
2.) All values in rows of that particular column should be filled with hyphen(-).

Below is what i have tried for, but not able to achieve my requirement.

Note: i should use Reporting API controls like XRTableCell. Other idea to achieve this is also welcomed.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;

private void tableCell12_BeforePrint_1(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    XRTableCell tableCell = sender as XRTableCell;
    double bancoAtivo = Convert.ToDouble(tableCell.Report.GetCurrentColumnValue("Campaign Count"));

    if (bancoAtivo = 0)
    {
        tableCell.BackColor = Color.Grey;
    }
    else
    {
        tableCell.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not your code looks like a typo.. Your code should work fine according to the way you implement but Column name cannot contain space and if statement is look well.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct but there is some gap in your description of the issue. I also suggest you the same approach if you just want to change the color of a single column cells.

> Handle the [XRTableCell.BeforePrint](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic) event and change the Backcolor
>   or Text property for the sender object. To get the processed record,
>   use the [XtraReportBase.GetCurrentRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentRowtopic) or 
>   [XtraReport.GetCurrentColumnValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentColumnValuetopic) method.

You can either use FormattingRules as described in the [Conditional Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument5167) help article or handle the BeforePrint event for the corresponding cells and set the BackColor for a sender object based on the processed value.

**Refer these:**
[Customize the Report Appearance](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument15041)
[Changing background of XRTableCell according to color value in data column.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T106453)
[How to change the XRTable background color?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q470870)

Comment: Here i need to check first row of data column, how to check or put condition so that if first row is zero or hypen in column, i need to grey whole column  and then replace zero with hyphen for whole column. In your link i get code to change color, i need to change color based on condition of first row of column.